# C++ read new files added to a directory

Tags: c++, file-io, directory, readdir, dirent.h

I have a C++ program that when starts, gets the list of all files in a directory and does some processing with them (packetizes them for transmission over network). The current version is static and the program only sees the files at the time the program starts. Now I want to change it to a dynamic version where it can continuously see the new files added in the directory (let's assume they have a meaningful incremented name; for instance f1, f2, f3, ... so next one coming would be f4. This way I can use some index).

Right now this is the piece of code (static reading of all files):

```
DIR *dp;
struct dirent *dirp;
char * dir = new char[inData->dir.length() + 1];
strcpy(dir, inData->dir.c_str());
dp = opendir(dir);
int file_index = 0;
int total_files = DataUtil::count_files(dp);

if (readdir(dp) == NULL)
    rewinddir(dp);

//for each file in the directory
    while ((dirp = readdir( dp ))) {
        string f_name = dirp->d_name;
        if (f_name != "." && f_name != "..") {  // except . and ..
            //Do some processing
            my_function(f_name, file_index);
            file_index++;               
        }
    }
    closedir(dp);
```

I modified the code using the `rewinddir(dp);` function and `file_index` to notice new files. But it doesn't work. Where is the problem?

```
DIR *dp;
struct dirent *dirp;
char * dir = new char[inData->dir.length() + 1];
strcpy(dir, inData->dir.c_str());
dp = opendir(dir);
int file_index = 0;
int total_files = MyDataUtil::count_files(dp);

if (readdir(dp) == NULL)
    rewinddir(dp);

//for each file in the directory
    while ((dirp = readdir( dp ))) {
        string f_name = dirp->d_name;
        if (f_name != "." && f_name != "..") {
        //skip files already read
        for (int var = 0; var < file_index; var++) {
            readdir(dp);
        }
            //Do some processing
            my_function(f_name, file_index);
            file_index++;

        //reset dir stream, and update total_files
        rewinddir(dp);
        total_files = MyDataUtil::count_files(dp);            
        }
    }
    closedir(dp);
```

The total_files function:

```
int MyDataUtil::count_files(DIR *dp){
    struct dirent *dirp;
    int num = 0;

    while ((dirp = readdir( dp ))) {
        string f_name = dirp->d_name;
        if (f_name != "." && f_name != "..")
            num++;
    }
    return num;
}
```

Here is the `rewinddir` documentation. It says ' might or might not be returned'!

```
Description:

The rewinddir function is used to reinitialize the directory stream dirstream, so that if you call readdir 
 it returns information about the first entry in the directory again. This function also notices if files 
 have been added or removed to the directory since it was opened with opendir. (Entries for these files 
 might or might not be returned by readdir if they were added or removed since you last called opendir 
 or rewinddir.)
```

Comment: You have few problems in this code, first of all you are trying to create an endless loop that will keep your pc busy all the time, then you are taking for granted that new files will end up at the end of the list but I would not be so sure. But beside those 2 problems and talking about your code you are assigning a value to total_files and you are doing anything with that.

Comment: @Marco Look at my updates. Looks like the count_files changes the dir pointer. The total_files is used in another file.

Comment: Looks like `myFileCount` function I was using increments the file pointer. So I have to add another `rewinddir(dp)` after `total_files = MyDataUtil::count_files(dp);`. At least it works now.

Comment: Look at the sleep() function - it will pause for a number of seconds if you don't expect new files to appear at a fast rate

Comment: They appear around every few seconds.

Answer (score 1):

Use inotify on Linux to get asynchronous notifications when files are added / removed / changed in a directory of your choice 
http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/inotify.7.html

Comment: Yes, I know that. One question I had was how to use a threaded version of that and use a queue.

Comment: Probably best you ask that in a new question. In short, thread, setup inotify in new thread, endless loop select on its fd, process events, mutex lock, enqueue, condition signal, mutex unlock, back to top all in new thread. In original, endles loop, mutex lock, while queue empty condition wait, deque, mutex unlock, use q item, back to top of loop of original thread

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way, maybe you can try it.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <Locale.h>

using namespace std;

void ListFile(std::list<std::wstring> &list_Steady)
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "chs");
    WIN32_FIND_DATAW FindFileData;  
    HANDLE hFind;
    LPCWSTR s = L"C:\\Test_Monitor\\*.*";//The path of Directory you want to Monitor

    hFind = FindFirstFileW(s, &FindFileData);

    if (hFind == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {  
        printf ("FindFirstFile failed (%d)\n", GetLastError());
        return ;
    }  
    else  
    {  
        wcout << "The first file found is " << FindFileData.cFileName << endl;
        list_Steady.push_back(FindFileData.cFileName);
    }  

    while(FindNextFile(hFind, &FindFileData))
    {
        wcout << "The next file found is " << FindFileData.cFileName << endl;
        list_Steady.push_back(FindFileData.cFileName);
    }

    FindClose(hFind);
    hFind = NULL;
}

void CompareFile(std::list<std::wstring> &new_list , std::list<std::wstring> &steady_list)
{
    bool bFound = false;

        for (std::list<std::wstring>::iterator it = new_list.begin(); it != new_list.end(); ++it)
        {
            bFound = false;
            for (std::list<std::wstring>::iterator steady_it = steady_list.begin(); steady_it != steady_list.end(); ++steady_it)
            {
                //Compare to origin list, if file still exist will return true
                if(it->compare(steady_it->c_str()) == 0)
                {
                    bFound = true;

                }
            }       

            //else this is a new file
            if(!bFound)
            {
                wcout << it->c_str() << L" new file detected" << endl;
            }           
        }

    bool bfound2 = false;

        for (std::list<std::wstring>::iterator it = steady_list.begin(); it != steady_list.end(); ++it)
        {
            bfound2 = false;
            for (std::list<std::wstring>::iterator new_it = new_list.begin(); new_it != new_list.end(); ++new_it)
            {
                //Compare to origin list, if file still exist will return true
                if(it->compare(new_it->c_str()) == 0)
                {
                    bfound2 = true;
                }
            }

            //else this file has been deleted
            if(!bfound2)
            {
                wcout<< it->c_str() << L" This file has disappeared" << endl;

            }
        }
}


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    list<wstring> Steady_Directory;
    list<wstring> New_Directory;
    DWORD WaitStatus = 0;

    Steady_Directory.clear(); New_Directory.clear(); //be sure that list is clean
    ListFile(Steady_Directory);
    HANDLE FileChange = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
    FileChange = ::FindFirstChangeNotification(L"C:\\Test_Monitor",FALSE,FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_FILE_NAME);

    if(FileChange == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        cout << "LOG : FAIL to get File Change, With error code: " << ::GetLastError() << endl;
        return -1;
    }

    WaitStatus = ::WaitForSingleObject(FileChange, INFINITE);
    if (WaitStatus == WAIT_OBJECT_0)
    {
        ListFile(New_Directory);
        CompareFile(New_Directory, Steady_Directory);
    }

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

I use two list, one stand for old state, the other is for the next state, and use **::FindFirstChangeNotification** to subscribe specific directory's state.
 
Any file change in the directory will set the HANDLE `Filechange`, then will call the function `CompareFile` to make sure which file has been added or deleted. 
You can make a for/while loop to make this monitor work constantly

Comment: [Here](https://imgur.com/a/l5iMf) is origin state of the specific directory

Comment: And [this](https://imgur.com/a/75bWV) is after adding New Text Document.txt

Comment: That is of course windows specific - the poster's soln is for any posix os

Comment: @MartinBeckett Oops, sorry I didn't notice that.